# JQuery and JavaScript methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, arguments

In majority of JavaScript method(iterator) callback first argument is element and second is index. But in case of jQuery always second argument is element and first one is index. Why they formatted differently? Is that for avoiding confusion between them, since both contains methods like map, filter, etc. Is there any special meaning behind that? I'm just curious to know.

Comment: No, there isn't. jQuery is a rebel in this case. See arguments of [`$.map`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and [`$.fn.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) callbacks.

Comment: @Vohuman : yup, in case `$.map` first argument is value... i didn't noticed that :)

Comment: Because you didn't expect it. This is an inconsistency and a confusing feature.

Comment: @Vohuman : yes, you are right.... when I started working in jQuery it's always confused me.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because jQuery relies on `this`; it doesn't need an element iterator.

```
$('selector').each(function(){
  // 'this' refers to unwrapped jQuery selector element; no need for arguments == cleaner code
  var $this = $(this);
});
```

In Vanilla JS, iterators rely on the parameters:

```
[].forEach(function(el, index){
   // 'this' refers to Window object; use the argument
   el.querySelector('foo')
});
```

Because jQuery can utilize the scoped element using `this`, it doesn't really need the arguments.  I'd have to look up the history of the library to even see if the element existed as the second argument in earlier versions.

Comment: can you elaborate more on the answer. this one is not clear this is more like a comment

Comment: @guradio if you chill out the answer will be updated ;)

Comment: yup that may be a reason, so the value arg doesn't have that much importance here :)

Comment: i was too excited to know mate :)

Comment: @guradio that sounded more snappy than intended, I've had a couple drinks and am laughing

Comment: This doesn't answer the question  ... the `each` callback does require iterator if using string array and `$.each` ... `this` will be garbage

Comment: @charlietfl : if string array, the this arg will be wrap by `Object` , isn't it? _[`The value can also be accessed through the this keyword, but Javascript will always wrap the this value as an Object even if it is a simple string or number value`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)_

Comment: @PranavCBalan no... try `$.each(['one','two'],...` and `this` ends up all wonky and is useless

Comment: @charlietfl : let me check that

Comment: @charlietfl : it's giving me an object like `{
  "0": "o",
  "1": "n",
  "2": "e"
}`

Comment: OK...sorry yes it does so have to convert back to string most of the time...easier to use element argument

Comment: @charlietfl the utility functions (e.g, `$.each`, `$.map`) are just that, utility.  They are more the fringes of jQuery; whereas the power of jQuery was the selectors and chained object iteration.  Needless to say, my answer should not be considered an official response from jQuery :) and there are exceptions; but your *this* would be a String object, instead of a primitive and would act as you expect under usual conditions except browsing via console.log, which will break out the keys for the object.

Comment: @charlietfl That's already a string, an instance of String object. Result of setting a string as the value of `this` keyword.

Comment: @Vohuman yeah but generally a pain to use as object IMO. I always use the element argument

Comment: @Vohuman : yup you are right... as per the doc this args always wrapped by `Object` in javascript